# How do I convert an epoch into a datetime, taking into account the time zone?

Tags: datetime, timezone, firebird, epoch, firebird-4.0

Can Firebird 4 convert an epoch to a datetime taking timezone into account?

Example:

Time zone is CET (+01:00).

```sql
SELECT
   EPOCH,
   SUBSTRING(CAST(DATEADD(SECOND,CAST(EPOCH AS BIGINT),TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00') AS VARCHAR(24)) FROM 1 FOR 19) AS DATETIME
FROM unix_epoch
```

Outputs

| EPOCH | DATETIME |
| --- | --- |
| 86400 | 1970-01-02 00:00:00 |

The required output

| EPOCH | DATETIME |
| --- | --- |
| 86400 | 1970-01-02 01:00:00 |

Comment: Did you try `SELECT EPOCH, CAST('86400 TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE' AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)`?

Comment: `<rant>`An _epoch_ in computing is the same as in astronomy: ["an instant of time or a date selected as a point of reference"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epoch). The Unix Epoch is `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`, because it corresponds with the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of `0`.  Your first column is thus not an epoch, but rather a _timestamp_.  (or, "Unix Time", or "seconds since the Unix Epoch")`</rant>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used too much casts, everything is simpler:

```
select dateadd(second, epoch, timestamp '1970-01-01 UTC') at time zone '+01:00' from unix_epoch;
```

Using timezone name:

```
select dateadd(second, epoch, timestamp '1970-01-01 UTC') at time zone 'CET' from unix_epoch;
```

Output:

```
AT
=========================================================
1970-01-02 01:00:00.0000 +01:00

AT
=========================================================
1970-01-02 01:00:00.0000 CET
```